# Flutter WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) error

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friends first off all sorry for my bad English.
I'm getting an error when I start debug my code in flutter-Dart.

```
          import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
          import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
          import 'package:get/get.dart';
          import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

          // Bu alan benim soru değişkenlerimi Getx yardımı ile tuttuğum classdır.farkllı değişken classları yazılabilir.
          class memberController extends GetxController {
            //5 benim değikenimin ilk değeridir.
            var _memberName = "a".obs;
            var _memberPhoto = "a".obs;

            //get ile çeker, set ile veriyi atarım.
            get memberName => _memberName.value;
            set memberName(yeniDeger) => _memberName.value = yeniDeger;

            get memberPhoto => _memberPhoto.value;
            set memberPhoto(yeniDeger) => _memberPhoto.value = yeniDeger;
          }

          void main() => runApp(MyApp());

          class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
            memberController _controller1 = Get.put(memberController());

            @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return MaterialApp(
                title: 'Material App',
                home: Scaffold(
                  body: SafeArea(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TextField(
                        onChanged: (Value) {
                          _controller1.memberName = Value;
                        },
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'memberName'),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        onChanged: (Value) {
                          _controller1.memberPhoto = Value;
                        },
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'memberPhoto'),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final uriAAA = 'https://www.meshcurrent.online/myWebApp/add_user.php';
                          var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                          map['memberName'] = _controller1.memberName;
                          map['memberPhoto'] = _controller1.memberPhoto;

                          http.Response response = await http.post(
                            Uri.parse(uriAAA),
                            body: map,
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text('SORUYU EKLE'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
```

This is my code memberAdd.dart file.
Target of this code.
-There is two textfield and I will get text from textfields with getx library. When textfields onChanged getx _controller1.memberName and _conroller1.memberPhoto chancing.
-I will send my datas from texfields to webserber when I pressed the Elevatedbutton.

But I'm getting this error

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.3/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:357:33: Error: Method 
   'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'SchedulerBinding?' because it is 
      potentially null. 'SchedulerBinding' is from 
     'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' 
    ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
      package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
     Try calling using ?. instead.
     SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
```

There is a lot of error text like this.

Please help me.
I'm using visual Studio

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2351).

You can use this [temporary solution](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2346#issuecomment-1125872217)

But in summary, just update your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  # ...
  get: ^4.6.x # Remove this line
  get: 4.6.1 # And replace with this line
  # ...
```

This will force to use a version where the bug doesn't exists.

### But where this error came from?

This error means nothing from your code but from `GetX` package which you are using in your project. So there's nothing you can do in your project to fix that.

You can notice it's not about your code by looking at the exception location:

```
C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.3/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:357:33
```

The `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org` is a directory where Flutter hosts the libraries you depend on.

Sometimes we face with exceptions/errors that are not related our project itself but packages/libraries/plugins we depend on. This can have **many** causes but the most commons are when Flutter has significative breaking changes and the packages don't migrate correctly, then the users of the package fall in errors committed by the package maintainer's.

### Solution approaches

To be quite straightforward: **there's no absolute fix**, but there's a right direction:

- Find where are the bug (which package? which repository?)
- Search for issues or PRs that mentions the same error as you (if you are luckly you'll find the solution in this step, which is your case right now)
- If you didn't find anything related to, search for a solution yourself and open a issue or pull request (or you can also just open an issue if you don't know how to fix, try to give much details as you can)
- Wait for merge and a new release with your bug fixes. You can either create a plugin fork which contains your fix and [make your project dependant of it](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages) (a version which has the fix)

Comment: Hmm I understand. Thanks for your help. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the package causing this issue has been updated to be compatible with the latest version of Flutter, 3.0.0. You can either:

1. Update your Flutter version to 3.0.0 or greater, or
2. Downgrade the package version to the one it was still compatible with your current Flutter version, removing the caret symbol (^) in the pubspeb.yaml.

If you choose the second option, as it might not be desirable to update your project to the latest version of Flutter right now, your best shot is to see the version history of the package and downgrade to the version before it was made compatible with the new Flutter SDK version.

If the version history is not clear, the other option you have is to go to the package issues page at GitHub (See at the right side of the package page at pub.dev, "View/report issues"), search if anyone has already reported the problem (you can use the search bar and look for "SchedulerBinding" or something like that), and see if anyone in the comments of the issue points out the version before the change.

If you still can't find the last compatible version, you can do trial and error for each version available in the version history of the package. Don't forget to remove the (^) symbol in the version of the package of your pubspec.yaml or it will still use the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't upgrade or downgrade the version of flutter, you can try this version of percent indicator (with double quotes).
percent_indicator: "^2.1.9+1" .
Then, clean and flutter pub get.

It's worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and the solution that worked for me is as follows

**probleme:**

`velocity_x: ^3.5.1` doesn't work with `flutter 2.10.`, because `^3.5.1` is for `flutter 3`

**solution:**

- step: 1
  in `pubspec.yaml` change `velocity_x: ^3.5.1` by `velocity_x: ^3.4.0`
- step: 2
  in `pubspec.lock` change velocity_x `version: "3.5.1"` by `version: "3.4.0"`
- step: 3
  `flutter clean`
- step: 4
  `flutter run`

i think it will work for you